# Problems with sectioning / toc

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering

I've got a problem with my ToC / sectioning.
First of it all: my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt, listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc, titlepage]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} %Type1-Schriftart für nicht-englische Texte
\usepackage{graphicx} %%Zum Laden von Grafiken
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing       %% 1,5-zeilig
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3 cm, right=4 cm, top=3 cm, bottom=1.5 cm]{geometry}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %%Fancy Kopf- und Fußzeilen
\usepackage{longtable} %%Für Tabellen, die eine Seite überschreiten
\usepackage{bibgerm}
\usepackage{color}  %% für Farben
\usepackage{tabularx} %% Für komplexe Tabellen
\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym} 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}% Die Kopfzeile soll
\addtolength{\headwidth}{0.5\marginparwidth}% verbreitert werden
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}% Keine Linie
\author{Matthias Fischer}
\title{Umsetzung der MSKBS in BA}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\chapter*{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\section{Einleitung}
\newpage
\section{Grundlagen Rechnungslegung}
\subsection{IAS/IFRS}
\newpage
\section{Rechnungslegung in der Bank}
\subsection{IAS/IFRS}
\newpage
\section{Bank Analyzer}
\subsection{IAS/IFRS}
\newpage
\section{Umsetzung}
\subsection{IAS/IFRS}
\end{document}
```

Okay, now my specific problem:
If I do it this way, all my sections are "listed below" the "chapter" listoftables. And I don't want it this way. I want it "listed" as normal/individual section and not as "subsection".
If I change my sections to chapters the subsections start numbering at 1 and not at 1.1 or 2.1. ....
So I'd like to transform my table of content list of figures as section or manipulate my numbering. But I think it would "look" better not to use chapters.

Is it possible to manipulate the "category" of toc and listof*?

Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The main sectional unit of `scrreprt` is `\chapter`, so either you use chapters instead of sections in the main part of the document or go to the `scrartcl` class.

Comment: Thanks for your welcome ;). Ok I will remember the document class scrartcl. But somewhere I read that I need to use scrrprt for my thesis...

Comment: If your school requests `scrreprt`, they probably want chapters.

Comment: No, they don't tell us what to use. If we can handle the formal requirements we could use NotePad ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `scrartcl`instead of `scrreprt` and reset the chapter Abkürzungsverzeichnis also to a section

Comment: Worked pretty nice. Thanks. Can you additionally tell me why my "ü" in "Abkürzungsverzeichnis" is not interpreted correctly? It is an A1/4 instead of "ü". It already worked but I must did something that it doesn't work anymore. When I have enough reputation, I will upvote your answer ;)

Comment: youre input file is utf8 encoded. Use `\usepacke[utf8]{inputenc}` instead of the `ansinew` definition

Comment: Works now. Thanks. If I could upvote all your answers I would do, but I have less reputation :/

Comment: @j0chn I will do that for you :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, `\addsec` is what you're looking for. See `scrguide.pdf` for more details.

```
\documentclass[12pt,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,titlepage]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addsec{Abbreviations}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ü is an encoding issue, you are specifying ansi, make sure your file is not accidentally saved as utf-8 aka Unicode (or change \usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} accordingly).