# Have unnumbered sections appear in ToC along numbered ones

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering

EDIT (before publication): I found the answer in this question: [Problems with sectioning / toc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104268/problems-with-sectioning-toc), but it's a little hidden, so I still choose to publish this question and answer it myself, as I think the question title describes my problem better than the question I extracted the answer from and I estimate it might save somebody else the trouble of looking for the answer in a less specific question. Here comes:

In my document, I have numbered and unnumbered sections. I want **both** in my ToC. I am almost certain someone else has been looking for a way to achieve this, but I can't even find out how to get to the question I am looking for, so, I'm sorry if this is a duplicate of another question, but I couldn't find it. I'm out of ideas as to what to type in the search field.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section*{Abbreviations or what have you}
\section{The First Section}
\end{document}
```

I would like this example to produce:

"

**Table of Contents**

Abbreviations or what have you ..................1

1  The First Section ......................................2

"

(Trailing dots to "align" the numbers. No dots for sections in normal ToC.)

Could something similar to `[heading=bibintoc]` be used? This one makes the bibliography appear in the ToC without a number.

[Adding unnumbered sections to TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11668/adding-unnumbered-sections-to-toc) and other similar questions do not hold the answer to my query, as they seek to take away the numbers to the sections and still make a ToC, but it seems **all** their sections are unnumbered. I really don't know what to look for. If you don't want to post an answer, but a link to another question with an answer that solves my problem, that's ok with me, of course.

Comments and better answers always welcome. I am a beginner in TeX/LaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick was simple, once I found it

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section*{Abbreviations or what have you}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbreviations or what have you}
\section{The First Section}
\end{document}
```

This will add unnumbered sections to the ToC and they will have a page ref like any other section.

Source: [Problems with sectioning / toc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104268/problems-with-sectioning-toc)

Comment: If you don't want to have to write  `\addcontentsline…` for each unnumbered section, you can automate it with `titlesec`, via `titleformat{name=\section}, numberless}{…}`.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199071/non-numbered-chapter-header-issue/199086#199086